# convert pandas column that is a string from 15 year 4 month 3 day to 15.3 years

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem regarding one of my column which has data that looks like this and I would like this to be calculated into years.

[image]

I tried using df.apply and split them up but I am stuck here. The formula should be like converted_years = years + months/12 + days/365

```py
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('C:/csv')

def years(c):
     y = []

     m = []

     d = []

     text = (c['years of service'])

     g= text.split(' ')        

df['converted_years'] = df.apply(years,axis = 1)
```

The result should look like this

```
converted_years
---------------------
10.8

15.3

0.2

2.0

0.7

10.9

0.0

1.9
```

Comment: Do have the strings `years(s)`, `month(s)` in your column or are you just using it to describe your question?!

Comment: I have all of them in one column

Answer (score 0):

So what you have to do is define a function which splits the string, applies the formula and returns the required number.

You can create a new column as:

```
df['converted_years'] = df['years of service'].apply(parse_string)
```

```py
def parse_string(duration_str):

    temp_list = duration_str.split(' ')

    strings = ['years(s)', 'months(s)', 'days(s)']

    duration = {}

    for i, string in enumerate(strings):
        if string in temp_list:
            idx = temp_list.index(string) - 1
            duration[i] = float(temp_list[idx])
        else:
            duration[i] = 0

    return duration[0] + duration[1] / 12 + duration[2] / 365
```

The function works given that the strings `'years(s)'`, `'months(s)'`, `'days(s)'` are exactly the same.

This should give you the answer.

Comment: it says list index out of range, it's most likely because some have all 3(year,month,day) and others have either only 2 or 1

Comment: You could use the elements of `duration` to make a `datetume.timedelta` object and then use that to calculate years, seconds, etc. Same basic idea except for the final line.